# Get base url in angular outside of component

Tags: angular

We're using the Msal library to handle authentication and it takes a redirect URL, which has to be the same one the user is accessing to work properly.

The config for that is in the app.module.ts, before defining the NgModules, so I can't get the router in a constructor.
Is there a way there to get the base domain the user is accessing ?

I have been using an environment variable to store this for now but it's very limiting, I'd like it to work for multiple domains transparently. Since the redirect url are stored and verified by microsoft anyway during authentication, passing whatever the user is accessing from the frontend should be fine.

Thank you

Comment: You could simply use document.location for that maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Hadn't realized this was an optional config :

```
redirectUrl: Location to redirect, can be a relative of absolute url. (optional, default: window.location.href);
```

The default is actually what I'm looking for, so nevermind !
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular Route, like that:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        YOUR_VARIABLE = this.router.url;
        //YOU CAN CHECK ON YOUR CONSOLE
        console.log(this.router.url);
    }
```

Comment: This requires a constructor, which I don't have where this config is, before defining the NgModules. But turns out not specifying the redirectUrl defaults to the current one

Comment: You can't use it on your app.component.ts ?

Comment: Well it doesn't have a constructor, the config is outside of any classes